# Rotating a GUI.Label relatively

Tags: unity

Learning Unity for 2D development, I want to create a text label.

So far, I have been using `GUI.Label` to write the text. It is above my sprite:

[image]

I would like to **rotate** the label relatively to the monster. In other words:

[image]

How can I achieve this? I have a feeling that `OnGUI()` is probably the wrong solution.

Comment: The new GUI system is available for use in the [Unity 4.6 beta](http://unity3d.com/unity/beta/4.6).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could get the rotation of the monster and then pass it into [RotateAroundPivot](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GUIUtility.RotateAroundPivot.html) before drawing the text. Alternatively if it's an option you could use the world space UI in Unity 4.6 beta to child the text to the monsters transform.